# What could be a scientifically credible argument that disk drive bad sectors are due to "normal wear and tear"?

Tags: hard-drive

As I understand it, electrical anomalies can cause corruption of data, and as a result, the check digit is off.  This renders the sector unreadable.  Read errors due to gradual "wear and terror" are intermittent errors that SMART is able to move the data to reserve sectors.

This question is being asked in the context of a first party insurance coverage dispute, as follows:

CONTEXT:
On September 7 2010, during a windstorm, my office experienced multiple electrical events which we were aware of only because we could see fluorescent lights flicker for moments throughout the day. On several occasions, one or two computers would shut down or restart during a flickering event. At the end of the day, our office management system, using an Oracle database was unable to save payments from a payment transaction. Our support technician came in that evening and reported that a disk crash.

A forensic computer engineer hired by my insurer took about 6 weeks to examine the computer and reported to the insurer that the computer failure was due to “normal wear and tear” that caused bad sectors on the hard drive.  My claim under my “Computer and Media” policy was denied due to the exclusion for “Normal Wear and Tear.”  Two forensic computer engineers have reported to me that hard drives do not experience “normal wear and tear.” The insurance adjuster reported to me that the electronic plating on the hard drive platter surfaces undergoes an aging process that causes bad sectors.

My understanding from reading information reported on this site is that “data” in the form of magnetic fields can flip-flop, and this takes at least 10 years from the time the data were recorded. The computer hard drive was only 5 years old at the time.

There were 12 bad sectors on the drive, and the bad sectors were overwritten with zero’s after a high-level reformat was performed.

The insurance policy covers data and software lost due to “electromagnetic injury” caused by:

> (1) Blackout or brownout; (2) Transients, spikes, surges and other
>   power failure; and (3) Airport security check, and radio or telephone
>   line interference;

The question is whether this forensic computer engineer has any scientific support for his position. Oh yes, he said that he had no other plausible cause of loss because there was no evidence of “physical damage.”

I am a software engineer with a bachelors of science degree in chemistry, and I can’t find any scientific foundation to support the forensic engineers position. I will be facing him in court in about two weeks and beyond.

The hard drive was on the application/database server, and one of the bad sectors was in the Windows System Registry Files.

We attempted to re-install the application onto a new computer with a new drive, but the application required a new Registration ID.  It never did this before.  A standard Registration ID was provided with the installation manual, but it didn't work!  The software support was transferred to a new company, but the new company could not or would not provide a new Registration Code because they said the OEM Copy Protection License product was no longer active.  It gets more complicated....

According to California Insurance Statutory Codes, the insurer has 45 days to decide whether to cover or deny coverage.  According to the policy, the insurer then has 15 days to determine whether to replace or repair the damaged hardware, software, and data, and how to do it and what to do it with.  If the claimant disagrees with any of the insurer's decisions, the claimant can demand a review by qualified independent appraisers, one selected by the insured, one selected by the insurer, and a third "umpire" selected by the two.  This seems pretty straight forward, doesn't it?

The insurer did not deny or approve coverage.  They sent me a "Reservation of Rights" letter that effectively alerted me that they found plausible evidence that I "may not" have coverage.  Then, they effectively put my claim on indefinite hold.  During that time, I found my own experts to perform a separate investigation and forwarded their reports to the claim adjuster.  According to California Insurance Code, the insurer must conduct a complete, thorough investigation with dispatch that is supposed to be "affirmative", meaning that it should be oriented toward "looking for coverage" instead of looking for reasons to deny coverage.  In fact, looking for reasons for denial, which is called in legal jargon a "pretensive investigation" is considered "fraud".

After 11 months from the date of loss, after I demanded the insurer provide me an independent engineer, the insurer the new independent engineer affirmed coverage.  Then, a new battle began; the evaluation of the loss and the amount of indemnification due to me.

If anyone is interested I will tell more of the story.

Comment: 0_0. Is the claim for the hard drive or other things? Sounds like a *lot* of work/money to avoid paying for the replacement of a single hard drive?

Comment: How inconvenient that your drive suddenly aged immediately after electrical problems that were insured.  Since the insurance company deals with hardware claims as their stock in trade, what are the odds that the expert is someone they picked at random, as opposed to someone who regularly does this analysis for them and relies on their continued business, which would disappear if it turned out there was actually a claim to pay?  They rely on the fact that it takes deep pockets to win in court.  Much of this "insurance" is basically a scam.

Comment: Are you claiming loss of earnings / business due to the event?  If the disk had crashed the week before, what steps would you take?  It seems to me that if your business is relying on computer systems never failing, then you might want to invest more time and money in the infrastructure rather than insurance.

Comment: This might seem sour after it happened, but: Plan for this to happen. Write a disaster recovery plan. Test it. Store a copy if it (as well as [hot] backups) off-site.  Update this at least once per year. It is a PITA to do and usually hard to sell to management, but if you ever need it it will make your life o much better.

Comment: As it turned out, the situation was unavoidable.  The new installation could not be restored because of copy protection even though the software license was a "perpetual license" and required daily backups!

Comment: I appreciate the comments that it is important to expect and prepare for disasters to happen. However, this one and possibly others are unavoidable. Laws have been placed on the books to protect users for these unavoidable circumstances. In particular, there are "user rights" protections and "implied warranties" that were intended to protect us from these occurrences, but they have no teeth! The law is not much use unless you have money... and when dealing with large companies, LOTS OF MONEY!! What I really would like is information about "Normal Wear and Tear" arguments that the insurer's for

Comment: What is the Model and Manufacture of the drive?  Drives are rated with something called MTBF -- Mean time between failures.  Server class drives have a higher MTBF, and that is essentially what you are paying for.  I would never (re)use a drive in production for a business critical application.  If you are running a business, you are likely not covered by consumer laws.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: If you've found evidence that the consultant is a "liar for hire", or even that he has a vested interest in the results (continued business from the insurance company), your lawyers could attack his credibility.

Comment: @Ramhound It's unfortunate that you can't allow answers to this question.  I'd like to give it a try.  To me at least, the question is quite clear, extremely urgent and important to him.  And, it is provided with a considerable amount of very relevant background information. An understanding of this question requires both hard drive engineering experience along with legal expertise to provide detailed information from which a logical conclusion could be formed.

Answer (score 0):

Were these drive failures in PCs or the database server? Were the payment transactions unrecoverable and the loss catastrophic? Is this for business harm due to the lost transactions or over a few hundred $ in equipment costs? You don't have to answer any of those, just my curiosity not my business. As an uninterested third-party with far too little information, my immediate thought is that if you're just looking for the cost of the drives you can probably get it just to make this go away. If you're looking for reimbursement of significant business damages based on the database being unable to save data due to failure of a single drive, you're opening yourself up to potential courtroom evisceration of your IT practices (power protection? RAID? "Enterprise" drives or not?).

To answer just your question, bad sectors can be relevant, but based on the best publicly-available drive failure dataset I know of (https://www.backblaze.com/smart) if "bad sectors" means SMART 198 then it does correlate to drive failure but does not have any significant correlation to drive age meaning "wear and tear" is probably not a good defense for the insurance company.

Comment: Electronics ware do not cause bad sectors. If they want proof, I'll give them access to my P1-233Mhz with WD 4.3 GB drive that has an uptime of over 10 years.  Note that each time you will try to claim something, the 'insurance' companies have their well established ways to make it so you don't get anything back.

Comment: The forensic engineer I used from DRG, tells me that the life of my drive is 18 years, and that they are still using drives in their shop that are over 10 years old.

Comment: @Overmind -- your 'proof' is anecdotal.  Payout rates on claims vary by insurer and policy.  When buying insurance, you should always check that.

Comment: @GordonEpstein, are you telling us that you are running drives that are 18 years old in production?  For business critical applications?  You are signing yourself up for heartbreak.

Comment: No, I'm not relying on old hard drives for mission critical applications.  That would not only be stupid, it would be slow, there would not be enough storage, and they would be unsupported by newer motherboards.  However, how do you check payout rates on claims?  This is very interesting!!!!

Comment: @Overmind -- I just googled payout rates, they seem to only be available in the UK and they are not available for First Party Business Insurance claims.

Comment: Yes David, because unlike the products today, the old products were actually made to last. I also got a 586-based notebook that still has over 1h of battery life. Try the new '2600mAh' cells to see how much they last. Not to mention the charge/discharge system. Since 1997 when I stared actually using PC I always tried to find the most long-lasting components out of a lot. So even if now I use a quad core with tons of RAM, SSD and RAID 0s, I still got functional things like an ATi PCI 4MB video card, old WD 4.3GB drives and SIMMs.

Comment: And guess what: W95 on a P1 233 boots faster than any machine today. So does an old Duron 800Mhz CPU on windows XP. So I'm not against using old stuff at all. They were quality products, made to last, not made to die.

Comment: "Bad sectors" are only one cause of corruption.  When the drive is spinning and in the middle of writing, and you remove power, that sector or cluster, that part of your drive will be corrupt, by definition.  However, the drive, the disk drivers, the operating system, the NTFS file system, the database app, and the app written on top of it all, is supposed to correct errors.  Often enough, they all fail and you lose the ability to even boot, or recover your data.  In addition, huge spikes are created by disconnecting a drive motor, in addition to lightning, both of which can corrupt data.

Comment: "Bad Sectors" appear as magnetic domains change over decades, or if the surface of the drive is damaged, which appears when the bearings in the drive, or the head mechanism wears slightly, or is dropped, throwing off the alignment so the drive.  Then it can't read sectors that were marginal, or becoming marginal. Bad sectors are usually mapped out without anyone knowing about it, until the drive runs out of spare sectors.  Relocating corrupt sectors when power is removed might fail.  It is improbable that only 13 defects alone caused your data loss.  The defects may have occurred over years.

Comment: Probability of failure on that night, rather than any other time points to the power outages.  Further, if the drive is still around, the Windows event logs would likely show exactly when these grown defects occurred, since they are generally reported by the drive in Windows to the event log.  Although your data loss may have occurred by the storm, as you probably have been told, establishing your damages is difficult, but it is also difficult form them to defend against.  It sounds to me that you tried to mitigate your damages by asking for immediate technical help.